# Node.js throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'testModule' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I looked around, looking for solutions for this problem else where and including here, but I keep getting the error

"Cannot read property 'testModule' of undefined."

main.js:

```
var testing = require('./lib/test.js');
console.log(testing.testModule('user'));
```

./lib/test.js

```
module.exports = {
    testModule: function(test){
        return 'Hello '+test+' from module!';
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error. 
In my original code (not here) I assigned the variable `testing` as `test` and called a variable that was non-existent.

Thanks for the tips on the directory structures, though. I appreciate it.

I suck :(